# dx fails with RoboGuice

Tags: android, dependency-injection, roboguice, dx

I'm trying to package an Android app which uses RoboGuice. The .class files compile fine, but when building the Android package, dx fails with a "No expanded opcode" message.

Running `dx --dex --debug --verbose target/android-classes` produces:

```
trouble writing output:
com.android.dx.util.DexException: No expanded opcode for 6c80c7f5 Key.java:371@0003: invoke-virtual v0:[Lcom/google/inject/Key$NullAnnotationStrategy;, com.google.inject.Key$NullAnnotationStrategy[].clone:()Ljava/lang/Object;
at com.android.dx.dex.code.OutputFinisher.findExpandedOpcodeForInsn(OutputFinisher.java:526)
at com.android.dx.dex.code.OutputFinisher.calculateReservedCount(OutputFinisher.java:467)
at com.android.dx.dex.code.OutputFinisher.reserveRegisters(OutputFinisher.java:403)
at com.android.dx.dex.code.OutputFinisher.finishProcessingAndGetList(OutputFinisher.java:359)
at com.android.dx.dex.code.DalvCode.finishProcessingIfNecessary(DalvCode.java:108)
at com.android.dx.dex.code.DalvCode.getInsns(DalvCode.java:185)
at com.android.dx.dex.file.CodeItem.place0(CodeItem.java:223)
at com.android.dx.dex.file.OffsettedItem.place(OffsettedItem.java:242)
at com.android.dx.dex.file.MixedItemSection.placeItems(MixedItemSection.java:312)
at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.toDex0(DexFile.java:543)
at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.toDex(DexFile.java:216)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.writeDex(Main.java:574)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:218)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:95)
...while placing CodeItem{com.google.inject.Key$NullAnnotationStrategy.values:()[Lcom/google/inject/Key$NullAnnotationStrategy;}
...while writing section 7
```

This occurs with RoboGuice 1.1.2 (Guice 2) and RoboGuice 2.0b3 (Guice 3).

In Googling around, I found [this previous question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805713/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-2-adt-16-0-1) which seemed to be a configuration error, but I don't think that's the problem I'm experiencing... help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this problem is related to Dalvik's [hard 64k method limit](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7147); I have filed a [new bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26203) asking the Android team to fix the poor diagnostic output.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite dx code, let it support  extended opcode. I hope my answer can help you.